# What is the probability that there will not be two adjacent children in the row with green hats?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A set of $20$ children - $10$ boys and $10$ girls.
giving them $20$ hats randomly- $10$ red hats, $5$ blue hats and $5$ green hats.
every child gets only one hat.

After handing out the hats to the children, they randomly line up.
What is the probability that there will not be two adjacent children in the row with green hats?

(I'm doing my best to translate this)

The answers:

1) $89/323$

2) $90/323$

3) $91/323$

4) $92/323$

Can you give me a hint?

I tried to solve this but my answers are not the same...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $N$ denote number of sums $n_0+n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=15$ where $n_0$ and $n_5$ are nonnegative integers and $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$ are positive integers.

Think e.g. of $n_0$ as the number of children at left side of the utmost left child that wears a green hat.

Let $M$ denote number of sums $n_0+n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=15$ where $n_i$ is a nonnegative integer for $i=1,\dots 5$.

Both problems can be solved with s[tars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Then the probability takes value: $$\frac{N}{M}$$

Comment: Thank you! could you clarify why is it 15 in the equality?

Comment: $15$ is the number of children that have non-green hats. Placing the children with green hats among them is splitting up that group (non-green hats) in $6$ parts.

Comment: Can I describe this equation as follows:
Number of arrangements for 15 children when they are separated with 5 partitions?

Comment: That goes too far. First of all there are $6$ parts (not $5$: $-g-g-g-g-g-$ has $6$ times $-$). Secondly we only look at numbers and do not distinguish children. Thirdly there are split ups that are essentially the same so there is some double counting.

Comment: by 5 partitions i meant 5 "plus" signs. Clear. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Simply compute favorable ways by considering placement of greens in $16$ gaps (including ends)

between $15$ "non-greens", then *Pr* $= \dfrac{\binom{16}{5}}{\binom{20}{5}} = \frac{91}{323}$